# Unable to create new publish layout

Tags: channel, publish-layout

Running EE 5.2.3 and trying to add a new Publish Layout for one of my channels. When I try to create or save the layout I get the following error:

[image]

The Super Admin group is already checked but it is read only and cannot be toggled. I can't move forward at all because of this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after digging deeper I discovered that I could successfully create Publish Layouts for other channels, so I deleted the existing problematic layout and was able to create a new one. Problem solved.